# In custom list view ArrayList objects are duplicating?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I do not know  what title should i give to this problem because my code is not giving me error.I do not know why it is behaving so. The problem is that when i click on _findButton for first time when it open it fetches 3 listview items and show in a list, when i click back i want the list item to be cleared so that i click again on _findButton it gives me same 3 listview items, but it gives me 6 items every one duplicated. I searched alot but do not know where is the problem. Please help me if you can. I am new here. Thank You.

```js
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

/**
 * Created by YouCaf Iqbal on 4/6/2016.
 */
public class MainGUI extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static  ArrayList<DonorPerson> Donors = new ArrayList<DonorPerson>();
    @InjectView(R.id.findppl) Button _findButton;
    GPSTracker gps;
    String bloodgroup=null;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;DB db;
    DBCursor cursor;
    DBCollection collection;
    Database dataobj = new Database();
    ArrayList allPPLlat = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLlong = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLNumbers = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLNames = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLImages = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLEmails = new ArrayList();
    public Spinner mySpinner;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maingui);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainGUI.this);
        Spinner spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.blood_type);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        _findButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getCurrentLatLong();
                dbAsync thrd = new dbAsync();
                thrd.execute();
            }
            //distance=Distance(lablat, lablong, curlat, curlong);
        });
    }
    public void getCurrentLatLong(){
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainGUI.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class dbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            getOtherLatLong();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainGUI.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching people nearby...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PeopleList.class);
            //intent.putExtra("DonorsList",Donors);
            startActivity(intent);
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Near by latitudes "+SelectedPPLlat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Near by longitudes "+SelectedPPLlong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void getOtherLatLong() {
        db = dataobj.getconnection();
        collection = db.getCollection("UserDetails");
        mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       bloodgroup = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
       BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
       whereQuery.put("bloodgroup",bloodgroup);
        cursor = collection.find(whereQuery);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject doc = cursor.next();
            // Lats longs used in the next for Loop for calculation distances
            allPPLlat.add(doc.get("lat"));
            allPPLlong.add(doc.get("long"));
            // All these other arraylists are used to store object of a donor person
            allPPLNumbers.add(doc.get("number").toString());
            allPPLNames.add(doc.get("Name").toString());
            allPPLImages.add(doc.get("image").toString());
            allPPLEmails.add(doc.get("email").toString());

        }
        // Clear DONOR objects before populating
        //Donors.clear();
        //Donors.removeAll(Donors);
        for(int i =0;i<allPPLlat.size();i++){

           double Dist= Distance(Double.parseDouble(allPPLlat.get(i).toString()),Double.parseDouble(allPPLlong.get(i).toString()),latitude,longitude);
            Dist=Dist/1000;
            if(Dist<20){
                Donors.add(new DonorPerson(""+allPPLNames.get(i)+"", ""+allPPLEmails.get(i)+"" ,""+allPPLNumbers.get(i)+"" ,""+allPPLImages.get(i)+""));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double R = 6371.0; // km
        double dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180.0;
        double dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180.0;
        lat1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180.0;
        lat2 = lat2 * Math.PI / 180.0;

        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2.0) * Math.sin(dLat / 2.0) +
                Math.sin(dLon / 2.0) * Math.sin(dLon / 2.0) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double d = R * c;
        return d * 1000; // return distance in m
    }

   /* public ArrayList<DonorPerson> getList() {
        return this.Donors;
    } */
}
```

```html
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by YouCaf Iqbal on 4/30/2016.
 */
public class PeopleList extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayAdapter<DonorPerson> adapter;
    int count=0;
   // public  MainGUI mainobj;
   // ArrayList<DonorPerson> Donors;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.peoplelistview);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //mainobj= new MainGUI();

     //   Donors.addAll(mainobj.getList());
        //Donors= (ArrayList<DonorPerson>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("DonorsList");
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        populateListView();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            for(int i =0; i <MainGUI.Donors.size(); i++){
               MainGUI.Donors.remove(i);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        for(int i =0; i <MainGUI.Donors.size(); i++){
            MainGUI.Donors.remove(i);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public void populateListView() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DonorsListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
       //count =  list.getAdapter().getCount();
    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DonorPerson> {

        ArrayList allPPLNumbers = new ArrayList();

        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(PeopleList.this, R.layout.singlelistitemview, MainGUI.Donors);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder MainViewHolder = null;
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.singlelistitemview, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                // Find the Donor to work with.
                DonorPerson currentPerson = MainGUI.Donors.get(position);
                allPPLNumbers.add(currentPerson.getNumber());
                //Set the Image of the Current Donor
                viewHolder.DonorImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                //currentPerson.getImage();
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(currentPerson.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

                Bitmap decodedFinalImage = getRoundedShape(decodedByte);
                //Bitmap RoundedImage = getRoundedShape(ImageBitmap);

                viewHolder.DonorImage.setImageBitmap(decodedFinalImage);
                viewHolder.CallBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);

                viewHolder.CallBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String number = (String) allPPLNumbers.get(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(PeopleList.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.MsgBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMsg);
                viewHolder.MsgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String number = (String) allPPLNumbers.get(position);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                        intent.putExtra("sms_body","");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.NotifyBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonNotify);
                viewHolder.NotifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Notify Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

                itemView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else{
                MainViewHolder= (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
            }
            return itemView;

        }


        public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
            int targetWidth = 200;
            int targetHeight = 200;
            Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
                    targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
            Path path = new Path();
            path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                    ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                    (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                            ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                    Path.Direction.CCW);

            canvas.clipPath(path);
            Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
            canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,
                    new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                            sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
                    new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
            return targetBitmap;
        }
    }
        public class ViewHolder {

            ImageView DonorImage;
            Button CallBtn;
            Button MsgBtn;
            Button NotifyBtn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yosuf, don't expect us to read that bunch of code and try to figure out what is broken. Did you even try to debug ? Use LogCat messages ? Was copying all that code necesary ?

Comment: You seem to have commented out the code that clears the list. Is that the cause of the problem? (In the first file, near the end of the `getOtherLatLong` method). It needs to say `Donors.clear();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please!

Comment: @UDKOX i have tried everything Sir.

Comment: @4castle that is not working as well

Comment: @YousafIqbal Do you expect us to read 361 lines of code ? Be precise in the question, what part isn't working ? What algorithm is failing ? Otherwise, you won't get any help.

Comment: The problem is in Arraylist declared in MainGUI class. I want to clear the items in this arraylist when ever i press back from PeopleList Activity

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are not clearing your ArrayList that provides the values for your ListView. To clear an ArrayList, just use `arrayList.clear();`

Put this code into your `onCreate` method for your `MainGUI` class. If you clear your `Donors` ArrayList, your application should function correctly.

Comment: Why don't you try clearing that `String[] list` as well?